# Would using intervals in this situation be okay?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm writing a website and I'm making a drop down menu from scratch. This includes a tab that once the pointer hovers over it, a drop down menu will become visible, all of which is wrapped in a container. To make sure there are no glitches with the container size (which is necessary as it is visible), I have two choices. One method to go about this is to call the function to update the size of the container three times, once on mouseenter(), second on mouseleave() and third on $(window).ready(). Though, another way is to call the function to resize the container every 60th of a second, no matter the conditions. Both ways seem to work, though I'm not sure  which one is better/correct. This would be the first choice:

```
$(document).on('mouseover', '.dropdown_container',
    function() {
        setContainerDimensions(this);
    }
)
.on('mouseleave', '.dropdown_container',
    function() {
        setContainerDimensions(this);
    }
);

$(document).ready(
    function() {
        setContainerDimensions('.dropdown_container');
    }
);
```

This would be the second option:

```
window.setInterval(function(){
    setContainerDimensions(".dropdown_container");
}, 16);
```

Here's my html:

```
<ul class="dropdown_container">
    <li class="tab super_tab"><a>Order</a></li>

    <ul class="dropdown">
        <li class="tab"><a>Cater</a></li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

As you can see, the 2nd way is much more code efficient, though I'm not sure it's the correct way to do it. What do you guys think?

Also, if you can think of a better option that would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: There is no generic answer to your question so you really should change your question to only be a specific one about a particular problem, not pretending to be a generic question.  All one can do is evaluate a particular problem and decide whether the needs of your code are better met one way or the other.  When lacking a driving reason to do otherwise, pick the simplest option that will make the code the easiest to understand, simplest to maintain and have the least chance for bugs.

Comment: can't you just do something like `$(document).on('mouseover mouseleave', '.dropdown_container', function () { ... });`?

Comment: Thanks @jfriend00 for the suggestion. I guess I was asking just for peoples opinions, but I realize I shouldnt be doing that.

Comment: Yes, questions about coding style are off-topic here. They might be more receptive at codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you're talking about a large amount of code, loading some extra code is not likely to have a noticeable impact. It slows the initial page loading a bit, and uses some more browser memory, but it doesn't have much impact on performance after the initial load.

Conversely, running unnecessary code frequently (60 times a second is frequent) is likely to make the page less responsive, because it will be interrupting the browser while the user is trying to use it. The actual impact of this will depend on how expensive the function is, though. You should avoid `setInterval` with small intervals when it can be replaced with code that operates in response to user-driven events.

Answer (score 2):

Use more code of course.

Using intervals means that for many times, the adjustments are unnecessary and wasted. I would suggest avoiding such a frequent execution of code, which may slow down the whole page.

More code is absolutely ok. Modern browsers are actually very fast to load and execute.